# Anti-Alias Text in Label Visual Studios

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, label, antialiasing

When creating a label the text doesn't have any Anti-Aliasing active making the text look sub par.
[Screen shot of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gqDG.png)

How can I achieve smoother text while still using the Label Control.
Winforms label and normal DPI 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: Is this a WinForms application on a high DPI screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Ah, I forgot the Winforms tag! This isnt a high DPI screen.